# how does it different between "to " and "for"

Tags: prepositions, for

In this sentence
"I threw a chair at the gunman. And I headed for the door."
If I say I headed to the door. how does it differ between
I headed for the door.  vs If I say I headed to the door. ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I headed to the door* may or may not be grammatical, but is certainly not idiomatic.

*Head* (in this sense) **requires** a *for* phrase. You wouldn't say *I headed.* There is no logic or rule which will tell you this: it's simply a property of the word, just like the sounds it is composed of.

(Actually, there is one construction where *head* does not require *for*, and that is in the expression *head off*, an informal expression meaning *leave*, usually with an implication of having finished a job or a meeting: *They said goodbye and headed off*. That expression could take a *to* phrase, but I don't think it would take a *for* phrase.)